# Why am I getting a VFP register arguments while adding a custom target to rust (arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf)?

Tags: rust, arm, target

I am following the guide from the last rust newsletter: https://rust-embedded.github.io/embedonomicon/custom-target.html and encounter an issue related to soft/hard float configuration.

I created my new target by merging the mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc.json with the arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf.json to obtain the following result:

```
{
  "arch": "arm",
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-p:32:32-Fi8-i64:64-v128:64:128-a:0:32-n32-S64",
  "dynamic-linking": true,
  "env": "uclibc",
  "executables": true,
  "features": "+strict-align,+v6,+vfp2",
  "has-elf-tls": true,
  "has-rpath": true,
  "is-builtin": false,
  "linker-flavor": "gcc",
  "linker-is-gnu": true,
  "linker": "/home/ykoehler/work/tools/arm-5.3-uclibc-1.0.12/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc",
  "llvm-target": "arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf",
  "max-atomic-width": 64,
  "os": "linux",
  "position-independent-executables": true,
  "pre-link-args": {
    "gcc": [
      "-Wl,--as-needed",
      "-Wl,-z,noexecstack"
    ]
  },
  "relro-level": "full",
  "target-c-int-width": "32",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-family": "unix",
  "target-mcount": "_mcount",
  "target-pointer-width": "32",
  "vendor": "unknown"
}
```

When I compile a no-std app with cargo using the new custom target:

```
cargo build -Z build-std=core --target arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf.json
```

I am getting the following error:

```
   Compiling app v0.1.0 (/home/ykoehler/work/app)
error: linking with `/home/ykoehler/work/tools/arm-5.3-uclibc-1.0.12/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "/home/ykoehler/work/tools/arm-5.3-uclibc-1.0.12/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-L" "/home/ykoehler/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/lib" "/home/ykoehler/work/app/target/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/release/deps/app-92459304df1651f0.app.2jjler86-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "-o" "/home/ykoehler/work/app/target/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/release/deps/app-92459304df1651f0" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro" "-Wl,-znow" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/home/ykoehler/work/app/target/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/release/deps" "-L" "/home/ykoehler/work/app/target/release/deps" "-L" "/home/ykoehler/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/ykoehler/work/app/target/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/release/deps/librustc_std_workspace_core-375ea25c872246b5.rlib" "/home/ykoehler/work/app/target/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/release/deps/libcore-34e07d1b528fc142.rlib" "/home/ykoehler/work/app/target/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/release/deps/libcompiler_builtins-a34a2e58700fb5e5.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic"
  = note: /home/ykoehler/work/tools/arm-5.3-uclibc-1.0.12/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/5.3.0/../../../../arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/bin/ld: error: /home/ykoehler/work/app/target/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/release/deps/app-92459304df1651f0 uses VFP register arguments, /home/ykoehler/work/app/target/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/release/deps/app-92459304df1651f0.app.2jjler86-cgu.0.rcgu.o does not
          /home/ykoehler/work/tools/arm-5.3-uclibc-1.0.12/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/5.3.0/../../../../arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /home/ykoehler/work/app/target/arm-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/release/deps/app-92459304df1651f0.app.2jjler86-cgu.0.rcgu.o
          /home/ykoehler/work/tools/arm-5.3-uclibc-1.0.12/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
          /var/tmp/tool-chains/buildroot-2016.02-5.3-arm/src/buildroot-2016.02/output/build/uclibc-1.0.12/libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/crt1.S:217: undefined reference to `__uClibc_main'
          /var/tmp/tool-chains/buildroot-2016.02-5.3-arm/src/buildroot-2016.02/output/build/uclibc-1.0.12/libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/crt1.S:235: undefined reference to `abort'
          /var/tmp/tool-chains/buildroot-2016.02-5.3-arm/src/buildroot-2016.02/output/build/uclibc-1.0.12/libc/sysdeps/linux/arm/crt1.S:235: undefined reference to `main'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `app`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

This error indicate that some code is compiled with soft float usage when other part is using hard float, from reading over the net about the error message.  Yet, both files specified by the error appears to have been generated by rust, and I am unclear why rust would generate any soft float code based on the information I provided inside the custom target definition file.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to use `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` for the `llvm-target`. The VFP error is related to the floating-point instruction set available (i.e. the hf in eabihf stands for Hard Float). I'm working on getting the `armv7-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf` target working in rust. I received the same VFP error while getting the `armv7-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf` target to work in rust and it turned out I just needed to use `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` for the `llvm-target`.

Also, here's my spec file for `armv7-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf` for comparison:

```
{
  "abi-blacklist": [
    "stdcall",
    "fastcall",
    "vectorcall",
    "thiscall",
    "win64",
    "sysv64"
  ],
  "arch": "arm",
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-p:32:32-Fi8-i64:64-v128:64:128-a:0:32-n32-S64",
  "dynamic-linking": true,
  "env": "uclibc",
  "executables": true,
  "features": "+v7,+vfp3,-d32,+thumb2,-neon",
  "has-elf-tls": true,
  "has-rpath": true,
  "linker-flavor": "gcc",
  "linker-is-gnu": true,
  "llvm-target": "armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf",
  "max-atomic-width": 64,
  "os": "linux",
  "position-independent-executables": true,
  "pre-link-args": {
    "gcc": [
      "-Wl,--as-needed",
      "-Wl,-z,noexecstack"
    ]
  },
  "relro-level": "full",
  "target-c-int-width": "32",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-family": "unix",
  "target-mcount": "\u0001__gnu_mcount_nc",
  "target-pointer-width": "32",
  "vendor": "unknown"
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Hi, so llvm-target would be use to "compile" but then at link time I use the uclibc to link with?  Is that the trick you are suggesting here?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You are telling llvm that it needs to compile for hard float by using `gnueabihf` at the end. I'm not exactly sure why llvm doesn't compile for hard float if you put `uclibceabihf` at the end, but at least `gnueabihf` works for llvm. Then the linker will know how to link the files with uclibc since you need to install the linker with uclibc. You can take a look at the arm-unknown-linux-musleabihf target as well, it does the same thing.

Comment: Were you able to submit your change to rust git repo as to get that target supported?  using your recommendation I got a stage 1 compiler, trying stage2, and then will build a toolchain for rustup and test it out.

Comment: I'm working on it. Here's a [link](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/new-target-armv7-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf/13284) to the topic I started regarding this target. You can get more info there and I also have a git repo that will build rust compiler for this target.

Comment: ok, I have a successful rustc/core/libc/std toolchain right now and my binaries works great.  I will see to submit a PR.  I could not get to run ./x.py test library/std I am unclear what is required to get this working, I am getting an error about missing ) parenthesis which I found on the net is related to incorrect arch binary run, meaning that somehow the test doesn't appear to kick in qemu and try to run the arm binary on x86 host (if I understood this well).

Comment: Created a pull request https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/79380 and here https://github.com/rust-lang/backtrace-rs/pull/396